# Check if record in a table exist in a database through ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, sqlcommand

in my program i need to check if a record in the database already exists in the table using the `if` statement.
using c# i am trying to do this through an sql connection.
as i supposed that the `ExecuteNonQuery();` command returns an integer value, if my supposing is true, i want to know what value is true to know that a certain record exists in the table or not. here's a sample of my code:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = dbUtil.GetSqlConnection(dbUtil.GetConnectionStringByName("NonConnectionString")))
{
    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from users where user_name like 'Adam' AND password like '123456'", sqlConnection))
    {
        sqlresult = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

considering sqlresult has been initialized previously in the main as `int sqlresult;`
so i would like to know, that if this user 'Adam' exists in the database or not. and if he exists, then i want to proceed with an 'if' statement saying for example:

```
if(sqlresult == 0)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Adam exists!");
}
```

so i just don't know the integer that it should return, and i am either not sure that this is the proper way to do it so.

thank you.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you want to check if the user exists, you have to change your sql and use `COUNT` or `EXISTS`:

So instead of

```
SELECT * from users where user_name like 'Adam' AND password like '123456'
```

this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from users where user_name like 'Adam' AND password like '123456'
```

Now you can use `ExecuteScalar` to retrieve the count of users with this username and password:

```
int userCount = (int) sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
if(userCount > 0)
    // user exists ....
```

Note that you should use sql-parameters to prevent [sql-injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) from users where user_name like @username AND password like @password", sqlConnection))
{
    sqlConnection.Open();
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", userName);
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", passWord);
    int userCount = (int) sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
    ...
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar() returns an Object not an int: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thanks for this great example, I have a question, from your 'using' block code, is the cast object to int missing from the userCount variable? or it isn't needed?

Comment: @WhySoSerious: thanks for noting, i've added it since it was missing. As @TonE has already mentioned it's required because `ExecuteScalar` returns `object`.

Comment: im wondering would this had a drain on performance? i.e does the count return the query results for `select * from ...` or just an int? Meaning you would have to check for the int value, then execute a query to return that result(s)?

Comment: Count just returns an int. But if you want the most efficient version use EXISTS and return a bit. It'll be more efficient because it can return the bit right after it found the first matching record while the COUNT has to evaluate all records to determine the count.

Answer (score 9):

You should be using [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) for cheking if the record exists. `ExecuteNonQuery` runs a transact-SQL statement against the connection and returns the number of rows affected for an UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE. It doesn't apply for SELECT statements

Answer (score 5):

I would use Select Top 1 Id rather than the count(*) because it can be much faster

Comment: This is true. Some time ago i gained a significant performance-boost because i changed it.

Answer (score 3):

You should do a `count(1)` on the table instead of a `select *` and then `executescalar` to get that integer value.

Using your existing code I would change it to be:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = dbUtil.GetSqlConnection(dbUtil.GetConnectionStringByName("NonConnectionString")))
        {
            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT count(1) from users where user_name = 'Adam' AND password = '123456'", sqlConnection))
            {
                sqlresult = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

Please note that I have used equals values instead of like values.

Also if I were do to this I would change your inline sql to use a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If someday you want to use EF just do:

```
private MyDb db = new MyDb();

public bool UserExists(string userName, string password){

   return db.Users.Any(x => x.user_name.Equals(userName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                         && x.password.Equals(password, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
}
```

Or do a generic method, so you can handle multiple entites:

```
public bool EntityExists<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : class, new()
{
   return db.Set<T>().Any(predicate);
}
```

Usage:

```
EntityExists<Users>(x => x.user_name.Equals(userName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                      && x.password.Equals(password, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```